# Replace '0' by 'nan' in an xml property using a regex in Dreamweaver

Tags: xml, regex, dreamweaver, replace

I have an **xml** containing errors.
Basically, if an occurrence of *'nan'* appear in a property, it's replaced by *'0'*.
For example, *nancy* become *0cy*

```
<user firstname="0cy" lastname="Ferguson" id="01234"></user>
```

I need to search the document and replace all *'0'* by *'nan'*, **but not in the user id**.
I guess the best way to do this would be trough a regex in Dreamweaver, but I don't know exactly how.
I can search all firstnames with `firstname="([\s\S]*?)"`, but this return all firstnames, not only thoses containing a *'0'*.
Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(?<!\sid=\"\d*)0
```

replace with

```
nan
```

---

explain:

```
(?<! subexpression)    Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion.
```

for example:

```
(?<!19)\d{2}\b
```

matches `51`, `03` in `1851 1999 1950 1905 2003`

Answer (score 0):

This is not elegant, but it worked.

**Search:** ([a-z])[0]
**Replace:** $1nan
If anyone have a better solution...